# background-image:url needs fixed width here, how do i change it?

Tags: html, css

```
  <div style="background-image:url('19.jpg');height:40px;position:fixed;width:1274px">hello </div>
```

I want to fix the position of this `div`tag but unfortunately I have to provide width to it i am not sure but I think its because of using background image and if i dont provide width , the background image does not flow to right corner of the screen. I want the image to flow from left to right occupy the entire screen width? How do i make that,any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: do you mean flexed width (as 100% percentage) to fix your whole screen by background picture? If yes, you cannot use background image, you have to use normal img and stretch it and use z-index to put it in back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `background-repeat:repeat-x` instead of width.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
    margin: 0 auto; //This is what you need, position: fixed is not needed.
    background-image:url('19.jpg') repeat-x;
    height: 40px;
    }



<div id="header">
    text
</div>
```